# Nested If statements, for loops and else if ordering in Javascript (FreeCodeCamp - lookUpProfile)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop

I'm currently working on Free Code Camp's Javascript tutorials and am stuck on the "Contact Profile" [problem](https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/profile-lookup#?solution=%2F%2FSetup%0Avar%20contacts%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22firstName%22%3A%20%22Akira%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22lastName%22%3A%20%22Laine%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22number%22%3A%20%220543236543%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22likes%22%3A%20%5B%22Pizza%22%2C%20%22Coding%22%2C%20%22Brownie%20Points%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22firstName%22%3A%20%22Harry%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22lastName%22%3A%20%22Potter%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22number%22%3A%20%220994372684%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22likes%22%3A%20%5B%22Hogwarts%22%2C%20%22Magic%22%2C%20%22Hagrid%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22firstName%22%3A%20%22Sherlock%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22lastName%22%3A%20%22Holmes%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22number%22%3A%20%220487345643%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22likes%22%3A%20%5B%22Intriguing%20Cases%22%2C%20%22Violin%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22firstName%22%3A%20%22Kristian%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22lastName%22%3A%20%22Vos%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22number%22%3A%20%22unknown%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22likes%22%3A%20%5B%22Javascript%22%2C%20%22Gaming%22%2C%20%22Foxes%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%5D%3B%0A%0A%0Afunction%20lookUpProfile(firstName%2C%20prop)%7B%0A%2F%2F%20Only%20change%20code%20below%20this%20line%0Afor(var%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20contacts.length%3B%20i%2B%2B)%7B%0A%20%20if(contacts%5Bi%5D.firstName%20%3D%3D%3D%20firstName)%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if(contacts%5Bi%5D.hasOwnProperty(prop))%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20return%20contacts%5Bi%5D%5Bprop%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%7D%0Aelse%20if%20(contacts%5Bi%5D%5BfirstName%5D%20!%3D%3D%20firstName)%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22No%20such%20contact%22%3B%0A%7D%0A%20%20else%20if%20(contacts%5Bi%5D.hasOwnProperty(prop)%20%3D%3D%3D%20undefined)%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%22No%20such%20property%22%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20Only%20change%20code%20above%20this%20line%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Change%20these%20values%20to%20test%20your%20function%0AlookUpProfile(%22Akira%22%2C%20%22address%22)%3B%0A). There's an issue with some of my if's and how they're nested/ordered. My code is below.

Specifically, **can anyone explain how to nest "else if" statements when you have two nested if statements in a for loop?** It appears the code needs to finish iterating first, but I can't get my syntax or ordering correct.

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
// Only change code below this line
for(var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++){
  if(contacts[i].firstName === firstName){
    if(contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
     }
  return contacts[i][prop];

}
else if (contacts[i][firstName] !== firstName){
        return "No such contact";
}
  else if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) === undefined){
    return "No such property";
  }
}
```

Comment: That didn't do it unfortunately, but figured it out and am answering my question now

Answer (score 0):

So the correct code is below, I had an issue with the first if statement, instead of using dot notation I was using "contacts[i][firstName] === firstName" which I think was causing it to not properly evaluate the first if statement.

If anyone could clarify why that could be, that would be great!

```
for(i=0; i < contacts.length; i++){
  if(contacts[i].firstName === firstName){
    if(contacts[i][prop]){
      return contacts[i][prop];
    }
    else{
      return "No such property";
    } 
  }
}
  return "No such contact";
```